# CiviEvent - there is no Change Selections button present for some registrants

Tags: civievent

An admin at our client accidentally registered some event attendees without making selections for them. Now she goes to edit their registration and make the selections, but there is no Change Selections button present.

On registrations where selections *were* made, however, there *is* a Change Selections button present.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: Is it in a price set, or custom fields? What kind of selections are you referring to?

Comment: Laryn, if as an admin you edit a registration that has paid options selected (from a price set), there is a "Change Selections" button, and you can change the person's selections on their registration. E.g. person signed up for Tuesday session of a conference but meant to sign up for Monday. 

But, if they made *no* initial selections - or if the admin entering them made none - then the "change selections" button is not there.